# Hide a field-set if Check Box is already checked and saved in database and if not checked then show the field-set

Tags: javascript, jquery

This my code

```
        <div class="editor-label" style="width: 110px;">
            <%: Html.LabelForEx(model => model.foo.f1) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field" style="width: 60px; padding-top: 0;">
            <%: Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.foo.f1) %>
        </div>
```

I want to hide this div:

```
     <div id = "newid"> </div>
```

using this script

```js
$(function() {
  $('#SecurityVulnerability_SecurityVulnerability').change(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
      $('#Security_AndroidPartnerBulletin').show();
    } else {
      $('#Security_AndroidPartnerBulletin').hide();
    }
  });

});
```

it's only working if checkbox is not already checked.
If check box is already checked then how can I write my JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just trigger it

```js
$(function() {
  $('#SecurityVulnerability_SecurityVulnerability').on("change", function() {
    $('#Security_AndroidPartnerBulletin').toggle(this.checked);
  }).change();
});
```

```css
#Security_AndroidPartnerBulletin { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="SecurityVulnerability_SecurityVulnerability" checked />
<div id="Security_AndroidPartnerBulletin">Hiddden at load time, shown if box checked</div>
```

Comment: Its working fine, But My CheckBox's position changed Automatically.

Comment: SecurityVulnerability_SecurityVulnerability this is my checkbox ID. Earlier it was near the label  like this: filed1 []. but now its like  field1  field2 []  in UI

Comment: Please show the rendered HTML in a [mcve] - your question is not related to your server code